# Backwards compatibility of Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, backwards-compatibility, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have developed an application which it runs on honeycomb. I wonder that can there be problem on Ice Cream Sandwich? What is the backwards compatibilities of ics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing is go try it yourself, ICS is already available in the Android SDK, install it and check if your app still runs. But usually android is pretty nicely backward compatible (there still might be some small differences in behaviour between the versions).

Comment: I tested it, when I run emulator using sdk14 it appears like mobile phones. When I changed its resolution settings as 1280 - 800 then emulator appears like tablet but characters and layouts are very big and text gets overflow of window. How do I set the emulator as a tablet while running sdk 14?

Comment: You need to choose the WXGA800 skin or check the density to be the right one (160dpi).

Comment: Thank you Heffer but i've got another problem which is saying [2011-10-26 22:32:25 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
[2011-10-26 22:32:25 - Emulator] 
[2011-10-26 22:32:25 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2011-10-26 22:32:25 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: Ok bro, I setted device ram size as 512 mb and the problem solved. Thanks again for your valuable answers.

Comment: I can run emulator on my quad-core PC with 8G of ram - it's damn slow, i literally wait for about 5 sec for any action. Will ICS run Android 2.x apps?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the API diff report.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/14/changes.html

If your app was built for 3.0, it should run on ICS.
It might need a different layout for smaller screens though

Thanks
Rajdeep

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.0 devices should be able to run your android 3.x targeted application.
But with the new apis introduced in Android 4.0, code designed for Android 4.0 may well not work on Android 3.x.

Its not hard to check your app directly.

I suggest you download the Android 4.0 SDK (make sure you've got the ARM image too) and try it on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

One area that I found to not be backwards compatible is the new res/layout specification based on screen size ( http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts ). This is a great pity because it is a far saner approach then the old layout-large, layout-xlarge, etc.